# Nested object and accessing value

Tags: javascript

What is the best to loop over the `headers` here and retrieve the Value for each nested object.  I do NOT want to hard code any keys.

```
let response= {
    headers: {
        date: {
            column: "Date"
        },
        name: {
            column: "Name"
        },
        age: {
            column: "Age"
        },
        height: {
            column: "Height",
        },
        weight: {
            column: "Weight",
        }
    }
}
```

wanted output:

```
["Date","Name","Age","Height","Weight"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Object.values` and `map` to pluck `column`

```js
let response = {
  headers: {
    date: {
      column: "Date",
    },
    name: {
      column: "Name",
    },
    age: {
      column: "Age",
    },
    height: {
      column: "Height",
    },
    weight: {
      column: "Weight",
    },
  },
};

const res = Object.values(response.headers).map(({ column }) => column);

console.log(res);
```